# Alternative object for RetrofitError when upgrade from Retrofit 1.9 to 2.x

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I am working on a project where RetrofitError is passed as a parameter of many functions in different place.

I am upgrading the project to use Retrofit 2.x at the moment. What Object should be used to replace RetrofitError?

I read the docs and seems like there is only something like response.code() or response.errorBody. Not really sure how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might have been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322186/how-to-handle-error-response-with-retrofit-2